# Import Error in IPython

Tags: ipython, importerror

I have a strange problem for my IPython. First the versions of Python I have, is 2.7.9 and my IPython is 3.0.0. My problems consist in: when I do some imports of packages I get the following:
In Python: import scipy, pandas, matplotlib, sklearn,... Here, it is working. But 
in IPython: import import scipy, pandas, matplotlib, sklearn,... Always I get the 
"ImportError: No module named ..."
After that I find out that i can fix it by adding the following, in every script,

import sys 
sys.path.append('//anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/')

Does exist any other solution to avoid this add?

Best regards,

Comment: Try  `export PYTHONPATH=$PYTHONPATH:/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages` and run again without the import. Add this line to your dotfiles.

Comment: It sounds like you have multiple python installation, and ipython is probably installed in a different one to the one you get when typing `python`.

Comment: when I run python in the terminal I get:

Python 2.7.9 |Anaconda 1.8.0 (x86_64)| (default, Dec 15 2014, 10:37:34) 
[GCC 4.2.1 (Apple Inc. build 5577)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
Anaconda is brought to you by Continuum Analytics.
Please check out: http://continuum.io/thanks and https://binstar.org

Comment: and for Ipython I get: 

Python 2.7.9 (default, Dec 11 2014, 02:36:08) 
Type "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.

IPython 3.0.0 -- An enhanced Interactive Python.
?         -> Introduction and overview of IPython's features.
%quickref -> Quick reference.
help      -> Python's own help system.
object?   -> Details about 'object', use 'object??' for extra details.